# How to reduce memory leak when using Scanner in Java?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java.util.scanner

I using Scanner for reading many logs file (~100 files), each logs file is ~120mb and have over 1,000,000 lines. The memory using for reading there logs file is continuous increase and cause memory overload. How to prevents this happen? Here's my code:

```
File file = processing.poll(); // processing is a queue.
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
String line;
int lineCount = 0;
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    line = sc.nextLine();
}
sc.close();
```

Thanks you!!

P/S: The memory increase slow, ~1mb for each file processed but I will push this code to the server and there're countless files in the future.

Comment: How do you know memeory leaks is happening and I hope you are closing  `scanner ` in finally block

Comment: generically, keep a pointer to the last record looked at and start at the next after that...if one exists. lot's of ways to do this, sequential, line key, timestamp. hard to say which is best without knowing your data

Comment: It is not because of "memory leak", it is because you are loading entire file into memory. http://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file

Comment: @primitiveType sorry, I forget copy this like to the question.

Comment: There is no memory leak in this code. *Ergo* this isn't the real code, or the problem lies elsewhere. There is a possible resource leak if an Error or RuntimeException is thrown, which is fixable via the try with-resources syntax. There is also a possible memory *overflow* if the input queue gets large, which just means you need to bound its size. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Nambari I using the option 3 in the page you mentioned and as they said this method is **not keeping them in memory**

Comment: @EJP I try to replaced the code above to `while (true) {}` and the memory didn't increase so I think there code is the reason make the memory increase

Comment: Impossible. You're now only popping one item off the queue, so the queue *must* build up and overflows memory, as I stated. But as you're only reading lines I would replace it all with a `BufferedReader` and a loop like this: `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to `close` the `Scanner` and release the file handle. Also, you could restrict the scope of the `line` and I think you meant to increment the `lineCount`. Something like,

```
int lineCount = 0;
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you might use a `finally` block like

```
int lineCount = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
try {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        lineCount++;
    }
} finally {
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: sorry, I forget copy this like to the question. I did it and this still happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are loading all of these huge ~100 log files into memory. Think about it. ~100 log files, that are ~120mb each. That's a lot of memory being taken! You are going to have to read in a single log file, process it, then release the handle on the file and remove it from memory, and then repeat until all the logs have been processed how you want them to. You need an algorithm that will process them separately and release the handle/memory as needed to avoid the overload.

Comment: Thanks you, I add all files to a queue and process each of them sequentially as you see in my code, not process all of them in one time.